# Score Corruption when upgrading to Optaplanner 8.34.0.Final

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

When attempting to upgrade to Optaplanner 9 I encountered some changes in solutions. Running with full assert revealed some score corruption issues that had not previously been present.  Tracing back it appears that the issue first appeared with Version 8.34.0.
The problem appears to be specific to `Bavet` as it does not reproduce when I switch to a DROOLS CS implementation.

It seems that the issue is possibly related to `Joiners` because by changing my implementation from something like

```
private static Constraint pegConstraint(final ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.forEach(Thing.class).map(This::getName)
                .join(factory.forEach(Hole.class).map(Hole::getPeg),
                        Joiners.filtering((name, hole) -> !hole.getPeg().isSquare())
                .join(factory.forEach(Hole.class).map(Hole::getPeg))
             .map((name, peg1, peg2) -> someAccumulator())
            .penalizeLong(HardSoftLongScore.ofSoft(1L), p -> p).asConstraint("constraint");
```

to using a filter like

```
private static Constraint pegConstraint(final ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.forEach(Thing.class).map(This::getName)
                .join(factory.forEach(Hole.class).map(Hole::getPeg)))
                .filter((name, hole) -> !hole.getPeg().isSquare())      
                .join(factory.forEach(Hole.class).map(Hole::getPeg))
            .map((name, peg1, peg2) -> someAccumulator())
        .penalizeLong(HardSoftLongScore.ofSoft(1L), p -> p).asConstraint("constraint");
```

the score corruption warnings go away, but the streams are significantly slower.  Am I misusing `Joiners.filtering()` or is something else at play?

Comment: Might you have a unit test with a ConstraintVerifier for it?

Answer (score 1):

It could very well be a bug, but since we haven't noticed so far, it'll be hard to reproduce. If you can provide an executable reproducer, that would be appreciated.